# Definitely can't figure out this triple integral in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to find the volume between the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ and the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$.
From the graph I can see they intersect when $z=-2$ and $z=2$. In the xy plane there seems to be a circle of radius 2. And since there's a full rotation around the circle, I'd say $\theta = 2 \pi$. But I don't know how to compute $r$, since the radius varies with height.

I understand the radius goes from the cone to the cylinder, however I'm not sure how to write that and how to set up this triple integral bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: the projection of the solid in the $xy$ plane is a disc of radius $2$. Then, $z$ ranges from the negative part of the cone ($z=-r$) all the way up to its positive part ($z=r$). Therefore:
$$
V=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^2\int_{z=-r}^r r\;dzdrd\theta = \frac{32\pi}{3}
$$

Alternatively, a slice of the solid at height $z$ is an annulus with small radius $r=z$ and big radius $r=2$, so its area is
$
A(z)=\pi(2^2-z^2)
$, and so the volume is
$$
V=\int_{-2}^2A(z)\;dz = \frac{32\pi}{3}
$$

Don't forget: if you choose $r$ as constants, $z$ must depend on $r$, or vice versa. You mixed up both options.